# Find the Laurent series expansion of $\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I want to find the $g(z) = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}-\{1\}$. My approach has been to decompose the fraction, i.e. $$\frac{z}{(1-z)^2} = \frac{A}{1-z} + \frac{B}{(1-z)^2} \implies A(1-z) + B = z \iff A = -1 , B = 1 \implies g(z) = - \frac{1}{1-z} + \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}.$$

Now I want to rewrite the sum in terms of power series. The first term becomes $$-\frac{1}{1-z} = - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k,$$

and the second one I do not know how to get.. This is my problem and I'd like some help. If I restrict the domain to be $|z| > 1$ the second term becomes $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-2}(k+1)z^k.$$

If $|z| < 1$, then we have $\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = (\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k)^2$, and I do not know how to continue from here. [I found an article on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138657/squaring-an-arbitrary-summation), but didn't know how to apply it to my problem and I also don't think it should be that 'complicated' in my exercise.

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^{2}} = \left( \frac{1}{1-z} \right)'$$

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Notice that we can also rewrite $g$ with some simple algebraic manipulation: $$\frac{z}{(1 - z)^2} = -\frac{1 - z}{(1 - z)^2} + \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2} = \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2} - \frac{1}{1 - z} .$$

To write a series for this expression centered at $\{z = 0\}$, we can use the observation $$\frac{1}{(1 - z)^2} = \frac{d}{dz} \left(\frac{1}{1 - z} \right). $$

> Formally (and analytically on $\{|z| < 1\}$), we thus have $$\frac{1}{(1 - z)^2} = \frac{d}{dz} \left(\sum_{k = 0}^\infty z^k \right) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty k z^{k - 1} = \sum_{l = 0}^\infty (l + 1) z^l .$$ Alternatively, reindexing $$\left(\sum_{k = 0}^\infty z^k\right)^2 = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty z^k \sum_{k' = 0}^\infty z^{k'} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \sum_{k' = 0}^\infty z^{k + k'}$$ by total degree gives $$\sum_{l = 0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k_1 + k_2 = l} 1\right) z^l = \sum_{l = 0}^\infty (l + 1) z^l .$$

Comment: But this is not the Laurent expansion of the given function in $\mathbb C\setminus \{1\}.$

Comment: This *is* the Laurent series of $g$ about $z = 0$ on the disc $\{| z | < 1\}$, which appears to be what OP is after (even if the question isn't worded entirely clearly).

Comment: Would it suffice to write $g(z) = \frac{1}{1-z} + \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = \sum_{k=-2}^{-1} (z-1)^k$?

Comment: @iaenstrom There is a sign error in the expression in the comment (the expression for $g$ in your original question was correct). It's not clear what writing that expression buys you, though, since (from your question it appears that) you're interested in the Laurent series of $g$ based at $z = 0$ that converges on the disc $\{|z| < 1\}$.